# How do I open activity from java class running a seperate activity?

Tags: java, android, events, android-intent, android-activity

OK, so I have an activity that starts on launch (Activity One) This activity runs two other activities (Activity Two and Activity Three) which each run java classes then load into another activity (Activity Four) on touch event.  Activity Four then opens Main Class.  All of these parts work exactly as they should.

The piece I am having issues with is starting a new activity (Activity Five) from Main Class and Activity Four.  I have my intents, my XML layout file, and my manifest created correctly.  Here is where it gets weird for me...

1) If I put Activity Five to start on touch event it works great (my touch events are in a switch case.  It works if I put it in Main Class which registers touch events or Activity Four which handles touch events for Main Class).

2) If I put an if statement into the touch event, it fails with no error (handler acts like the event never happens), unless I put Activity Five to start in every "if" statement (this is the same whether I use just "if" or multiple, non-nested "if" statements, or "if/else if" statements.  The result is always the same, handler acts like no touch event happened unless all if statements start Activity Five).

3) If I put Activity Five to start anywhere else in any Activity or the Main Class with any parameters at all I get an error saying I can't start the activity from a handler without Looper.prepare().  If I put Looper.prepare() into the intent call method it then errors saying null pointer exception at my startActivity(ActivityFive) call.

Let me try and be 100% clear here...

I don't change the intent call or startActivity() call at all.  The only thing I change is the location and surrounding qualifiers (if statements).  For some reason, the startActivity call only works if I put it in a touch event and start the activity no matter what qualifier registers as true.

My other activities are all started from touch events or smooth auto-flow between each other.

Activity Five needs to be started by either:

1)    If statement outside of touch event handler:

```
  if (object1.isGone)
  {

      ...

      ActivityFour aFour = new ActivityFour();
      Intent aFive = new Intent (afour, ActivityFive.class)
      aFour.startActivity(aFive);

  }

  if (!object1.isGone)
  {

      (do nothing)

  }
```

2)  Or if statement inside a touch event handler:

```
  switch (screen.touchAction)
  {

      case screen.touch_Middle:

           if (object1.isGone)
           {

                ...
                ActivityFour aFour = new ActivityFour();
                Intent aFive = new Intent (afour, ActivityFive.class)
                aFour.startActivity(aFive);

           }

           if (!object1.isGone)
           {

               (do nothing)

           }

        break;
```

Thank you for your help and I'll be sure to +1 and check the answer that solves this insanity.

Comment: what is `object1.isGone`?

Comment: visible = true vs visible = false.  Closest well known example I can think of would be:  if player is dead start Activity Five.  If player is not dead do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You have this:

```
  ActivityFour aFour = new ActivityFour();
  Intent aFive = new Intent (afour, ActivityFive.class)
  aFour.startActivity(aFive);
```

You **absolutely positively cannot** create an instance of an `Activity` using `new`! Only the Android framework can create instances of Android components (activity, service, broadcast receiver, content provider). This is due to the way that these components require the Android framework to set up the correct `Context` during the instantiation.

If you just want to start an `Activity` from `MainClass`, you will need to pass a `Context` instance to `MainClass` either when you create the instance of `MainClass` or sometime later with a `set...()` method before you need to use it. Then, when you want to start an `Activity`, you can do this:

```
Intent aFive = new Intent (afour, ActivityFive.class)
context.startActivity(aFive);
```

The `Context` can either be an `Activity` (which inherits from `Context`) or it can be the global application context which you can get in an `Activity` using `getApplicationContext()`.

Comment: OK, I like where you are going with this, and I have been in the same thought process.  The only thing is, the context only works if I attach the startActivity to a button click event or some other type of event handler.  If I attach the startActivity(aFive) call to a non event handler, it stops working.  Is there a special line syntax or call I have to make to NOT use an event handler like a touch event?  Also, my apologies for going MIA for the week.  Life got crazy for a few days.

Comment: A little better question.  I have this exact syntax functioning properly in opening a new activity on touch event (button click event).  How do I get it to now work on Boolean = true event?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. You can start an activity any time you want. It doesn't need to be tied to some event. There must be some other problem. Maybe you should post more code or write a small test program to test out exactly this case.